# SwiftUI - How to use onCommand with NSMenuItem on macOS

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I am trying to find the best solution to connect a NSMenuItem with SwiftUI onCommand on macOS.

Currently I an doing the following:

1. In AppDelegate I create a dummy function to be able to list the function First Responder received actions list.

```
@IBAction func changeColor(_ sender: Any) {
    print("Dummy Function")
}
```

2. Create and connect a NSMenuItem with the First Responder function in the Main.storyboard.
3. Add the required code to my SwiftUI view

```
struct TestView: View {

    let changeColor = #selector(AppDelegate.changeColor(_:))

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Text", text: .constant(""))
            Text("Hello World!")
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .onCommand(changeColor) {
            print("Change Color Action")
        }
    }
}
```

If the TextField was First Responder before I will see that "Change Color Action" is printed.
The View will not become First Responder if the TextField was not First Responder before. Maybe this is currently a bug in Catalina Beta (19A558d) since I don't get focusable to work as well.

Comment: Can you rephrase your closing paragraph to describe the problem more clearly?

Comment: Hey, It is irrelevant with your question but did you construct your `NSMenu` using SwiftUI?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I have a similar situation, would love to know if you made any progress.

Answer (score 3):

I've been able to get this to work by first making the view `focusable`:

```swift
struct TestView: View {

    let changeColor = #selector(AppDelegate.changeColor(_:))

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            TextField("Text", text: .constant(""))
            Text("Hello World!")
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
        .focusable() // Add this 
        .onCommand(changeColor) {
            print("Change Color Action")
        }
    }
}
```

then you also have to check the "Use keyboard navigation to move focus between controls" checkbox in Keyboard System Preferences

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am aware of the preference settings but not many user will turn this setting on (me either). In normal macOS development you can make any custom view become the first responder without to turn this functionality on. I am still looking for a completely satisfying solution.

Comment: That seems to do the trick, but what's the connection between `onCommand` and that setting?

Comment: @Bill In the SwiftUI docstrings for `onCommand` it says "The view or one of the views it contains must be in focus for the action to trigger. ..."

`.focusable()` and that setting must allow that? I still couldn't get it to work though.

Comment: I've tried to reproduce your example. But for me, it doesn't work! It's only got called @IBAction func changeColor and never onCommand(changeColor). I will be grateful to see the real use case of this onCommand modifier! :)

Answer (score 1):

I ended up creating a `PassthroughSubject` in my AppDelegate, passing it through to my SwiftUI view, and subscribing to it in the model object owned by my SwiftUI view. When my AppDelegate selector for the menu command is called, I send the event using the `PassthroughSubject`, which my model receives and handles appropriately.

My answer is definitely not ideal, and I'd love to know if you figure out a better way to do this.