# How to connect a storyboard interface to a SwiftUI (macOS) AppDelegate?

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

Since there seems to be no direct way to create a toolbar (NSToolbar) in macOS SwiftUI, I am trying to create the toolbar on storyboard and then link it to the application. However, as expected, Xcode does not allow me to create outlets to an unlinked file, which goes into `NSViewController` territory. Is there a way to link a storyboard toolbar to a SwiftUI structure? If required, how does `NSViewRepresentable` takes a role in this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try to follow this approach https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58049065/swiftui-how-to-use-oncommand-with-nsmenuitem-on-macos

Comment: Thank you! I'll have a look at it.